# parameters FDquery delphi does not work

Tags: sql, delphi, parameters

i have the following delphi code:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
FDQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM :Tablename');
FDQuery1.ParamByName('Tablename').AsString := 'tasks';
ShowMessage(FDQuery1.sql.Text);
FDQuery1.Open;
```

(coppied from this link: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/da/237634.html)

it does not work because the parameter is not filled but stays the same.
does somebody know why it is not filled?

Comment: You cannot specify tablename using a parameter. Parameters are for column values.

Comment: ah, ok. thank you.

Comment: Generally you use parameters when the value is provided at runtime, or needs to be escaped. Here you have a literal value, `'tasks'` that contains only ASCII characters. Even for a column value you would have no real need to use parameters for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you cannot use parameters for table name substitution in SQL commands in general. You are lucky enough here though, FireDAC supports preprocessor macros to parametrize table names in SQL commands. So you can write for example this (note that if you want to see the command as you did in your code, it must be after macro preprocessing, that is e.g. after calling [**Prepare**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDRdbmsDataSet.Prepare)):

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM &TableName';
FDQuery1.MacroByName('TableName').AsIdentifier := 'tasks';
FDQuery1.Open;
```

For details about this kind of macros, see the [**substitution variables**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Substitution_Variables) topic.