# EOleException with message 'Syntax error in FROM clause' delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

Hi I'm trying to get SQL to select from a table which the user has chosen from a list box

Heres my code

```
activity := cmbActivity.Text; //this is where the user selects a table to choose from
qryStudents.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM :activity WHERE CompNo = :iCompNo'; //error here
qryStudents.Parameters.ParamByName('activity').Value:= activity; 
qryStudents.Parameters.ParamByName('iCompNo').Value := iCompNo;
qryStudents.Open;
```

I keep getting a syntax error after FROM in the SQL code (:activity) 
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define the table part of your select as a parameter, you'll need to dynamically build that part of the select statement.

```
activity := cmbActivity.Text;
qryStudents.Close;
qryStudents.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM '  + activity + ' WHERE CompNo = :iCompNo';
qryStudents.Parameters.ParamByName('iCompNo').Value := iCompNo;
qryStudents.Open;
```

:iCompNo OTOH is fine to be defined as a parameter, in order to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: It still gives the same issue with that change

Comment: Are you sure that the activity variable had a valid table name ?. By the way, you had a qryStudents.Edit at the start of your code, I have changed it for qryStudents.Close, because your query should be closed when you change its SQL property.

Comment: Yes it is a valid table name. I did close the qryStudents.Edit before I worked on this snippet. I get a syntax error on exactly how it is in the title which breaks my program

Comment: @JaynillGopal:   Marc is right that you cannot specify the table you are querying using a parameter, so +1 for that.  Which Sql back-end and Delphi query component are you using.

Comment: I'm using an ADOQuery component in delphi with a Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 connection

Comment: Is there another way of selecting a table which the user chooses if I cant use SQL

Comment: With FireDAC you could use substitution variables [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280825/8041231). Though they are not real parameters hence the command needs to be prepared for execution every time you change the macro substitution variable value. For ADO components use the way proposed in this answer.

Comment: If your table name has uppercases and lowercases, try to enclose that name within []. This way : qryStudents.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM ['  + activity + '] WHERE CompNo = :iCompNo';

Comment: @MarcGuillot, case sensitivity applies only if [Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-microsoft-jet#connection-dynamic-properties) is explicitly set.